# Raspberry PI python script with PR sensor

Tags: python

I have a raspberry PI set-up on my network and I'm tracking movement from a PR sensor. As per this article: http://nicomiceli.com/tracking-your-home-with-google-analytics/

I'm sending movement as hits to Google Analytics with success. However, I'm noticing that any movement is sending multiple hits or triggering multiple times.

Is there any suggestion of amends to the code that could reduce the re-triggering to minimise this issue?

Answer (score 1):

update: adding something like

time.sleep(0.01)

at the end of the function before looping seems to do the trick fairly well so far as per the example here: http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/01/cheap-pir-sensors-and-the-raspberry-pi-part-1/